# Same function on multiple div classes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing something terribly wrong and just can't find the solution for it.

**Situation:**
I've got a number of products with a number of quotes per product. Those quote automatically scroll in a div. If the scroll reaches the last quote is scroll back to the first one.

**What works:**
The function basically works when it's applied on 1 div, but when applied on multiple div it doesn't scroll back to the first one or keeps scrolling endlessly.

This is the function i've written for this:

```
function quoteSlide(divname){
$total = ($(divname+" > div").size())
$width = $total * 160;
$(divname).css('width', ($width));
console.log ($totalleft *-1);
if ($width - 160 > $totalleft *-1){ 
    $currentleft =  $(divname).css('left');
    $step = -160;
    $totalleft = parseInt($currentleft)+$step;
}else{
    $totalleft = 0;
}

$(divname).animate(
    { 
        left: $totalleft
    }, // what we are animating
    'slow', // how fast we are animating
    'swing', // the type of easing
    function() { // the callback
    });
```

}

It's being executed by something like: `quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');` in combination with a setInterval so it keeps scrolling automatically.

This is the jsFiddle where it goes wrong (So applied on more than 1 div) http://jsfiddle.net/FsrbZ/.
This is the jsFiddle where everything goes okay. (applied on 1 div)

When changing the following:

```
   quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');
   quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_2');
setInterval(function() {
     quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');
     quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_2');
}, 3400);​
```

to

```
quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');

setInterval(function() {
     quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');
}, 3400);​
```

it does work... but only on 1 quotecontainer.

Comment: You can find it in the jsFiddle. The problem isn't in the HTML (I think ;-)), that's why i didn't post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This works.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysevq/) As already mentioned by Matei Mihai, the `$totalleft` variable was shared among the calls. Further, I have also moved the `setInterval` call into the `quoteSlide()`function, so you don't have to repeat yourself.

I have moved the variable into the `quoteSlide()` function, so every call gets its own instance of that variable.

Another thing about JavaScript:

- Javascript is *not* PHP, you don't need to prefix your variables with a `$`-sign! Personally, I use the convention to prefix all jQuery objects with a `$`.

PS: You may want to remove the first call to `callback()`, to allow the visitor to actually read the first quote. I have included it because that's the way it worked in your original code.

---

```
function quoteSlide(divname) {
    var $totalleft = 0;
    var callback = function() {
        $total = ($(divname + " > div").size())
        $width = $total * 160;
        $(divname).css('width', ($width));
        if ($width - 160 > $totalleft * -1) {
            $currentleft = $(divname).css('left');
            $step = -160;
            $totalleft = parseInt($currentleft) + $step;
        } else {
            $totalleft = 0;
        }

        $(divname).animate({
            left: $totalleft
        }, 'slow', 'swing', function() {});
    };
    callback(); # <-- I would remove this
    setInterval(callback, 3400);
}

quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_1');
quoteSlide('#quotecontainer_2');​
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your function uses the same `$totalleft` variable for all calls, so when you call the function multiple times, the number you store in the `$totalLeft` variable is not correct.

Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/FsrbZ/3/

```
var $totalleft = new Array();
function quoteSlide(divname){
    $total = ($(divname+" > div").size())
    $width = $total * 160;
    $(divname).css('width', ($width));
    if ($width - 160 > $totalleft[divname] *-1){ 
        $currentleft =  $(divname).css('left');
        $step = -160;
        $totalleft[divname] = parseInt($currentleft)+$step;
    }else{
        $totalleft[divname] = 0;
    }

    $(divname).animate(
        { 
            left: $totalleft[divname]
        },
        'slow', 
        'swing',
        function() { 
        });
}
```

Comment: Seems legit... But how do i create a new $totalleft for every new quotecontainer? Isn't that where a function is for, so you only have to write the code once? Or can I make it dynamic in some way?

Comment: That would be it! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Using a global variable for that isn't very nice, though ;)

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel just upvote Matei's as well, and have a look at his other answers to and see if you like other answers of his ;)

Comment: No problem.. he's right.. I found an workaround for your solution but @phant0m's solution is better

Comment: @phant0m what do you mean? :)) what's the problem with my answers?

Comment: Not a problem, it's just a way to "say thanks" by giving you some additional rep on other good answers of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some were faster, but here's yet another solution, that's works: http://jsfiddle.net/FsrbZ/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/FsrbZ/10/

I added a if statement that resets the variable when it is less than -490 (when the counter gets to step 4)

Answer (score 0):

What's about

`$total = ($(divname+" div").size())` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/FsrbZ/2/

Let me know if that is what you want